# Pandas: Python check Multiple columns if contains value then return value to new column

Tags: python, pandas

Currently facing an issue (data cleaning) of looking at multiple columns in a df that contain the word "food" and then creating a new column named 'food' with the found value

I can search for each specific column however running into issues when searching through the entire dataset (looking at every column and not overriding the previous entry)

```
s = df['tag_1'].str.contains('food')
df['food'] = df.tag_1.where(s)
```

Current:

| tag_1 | tag_2 | tag_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| placeholder | placeholder | French food |
| British food | placeholder | placeholder |
| placeholder | German food | placeholder |

Ideal:

| tag_1 | tag_2 | tag_3 | food |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| placeholder | placeholder | French food | French food |
| British food | placeholder | placeholder | British food |
| placeholder | German food | placeholder | German food |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can mask and `bfill` to get the first match:

```
mask = df.apply(lambda c: c.str.contains('food'))

df['food'] = df.where(mask).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

output:

```
          tag_1        tag_2        tag_3          food
0   placeholder  placeholder  French food   French food
1  British food  placeholder  placeholder  British food
2   placeholder  German food  placeholder   German food
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some additional ways by first stacking the data.

```
s = df.stack()
df.assign(food = s.loc[s.str.contains('food').loc[lambda x: x].index].to_numpy())
```

or

```
df.assign(food = df.stack().where(lambda x: x.str.contains('food')).groupby(level=0).first())
```

Output:

```
          tag_1        tag_2        tag_3          food
0   placeholder  placeholder  French food   French food
1  British food  placeholder  placeholder  British food
2   placeholder  German food  placeholder   German food
```